# 4x4 matrix with colours and symbols - no repeat in row or column

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

I was watching Survivor (reality show) and they got a following puzzle.
There is 4x4 matrix where each column has a color and each row has a symbol.

By moving around or replacing you should get to the point, where in each row or column there is no repeating symbol or repeating color.

I was able to solve that, but I cannot explain how. I think this is some variant of Algebraic magic square. But is there some algorithm which I could always follow to get to the final required state?

[image]

Comment: @138Aspen Actually, a [Graeco-Latin Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares).

Comment: Interesting, I was watching the same show and I also thought about it being an algebraic problem. Edit: Maybe to add, my solution focused on constructing the diagonals first, after I first tried to go row by row